# Custom WinUI 3 C++/WinRT Control in C# WinUI project

Tags: c#, c++-winrt, winui-3

I am trying to create WinUI C++/WinRT Component containing XAML control and iclude this custom control inside C# WinUI 3 project. Is this somehow possible? I had no luck yet. Could you please provide some examples if this is possible?

#### Reason:

Since WinUI 3 does not offer media player I want to make media player like this:
https://github.com/asklar/WinAppSDK-MediaPlayer

#### EDIT:

So far I found [WinRT APIs not supported in .NET 5 or later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance#winrt-apis-not-supported-in-net-5-or-later). I found there *Windows.UI.Xaml (all classes in this namespace)* which seems to be needed for creating custom c++/winrt control. After I read this I assume that it is not possible to consume custom C++/WinRT WinUI
control in C# WinUI project.

[image]

#### Example:

Those are steps I created that projects.

- Check this topic [MS Docs](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT/tree/master/src/Samples/NetProjectionSample)
- [Link to example](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT/tree/master/src/Samples/NetProjectionSample)

1. Create C# Library
2. Create WinUI C++ Component
3. Setup accordingly to MS Docs and Example
4. Add WindowsSdk reference to library project
5. Add custom control to C++ project

What I found possible is to consume custom C# WinUI contron inside WinUI C++/WinRT project, which seems to be way to go for me.

Comment: *"Is this somehow possible?"* - Seeing that WinUI is implemented in C++ in its entirety, and using it from C# is supported I'm confused as to why this question even comes up.

Comment: I just could not make it work. I tried to create WinUI C++/WinRT component and include it in WinUI C# project but I could not build solution. So that is why I am asking if it is possible and if there are any examples. I could not find anything helpful in MS Docs. I might be doing something wrong so that's why I am asking for help...

Comment: Today I found article which might answer my question why I could not make it work for UI contro... It seem to be not supported. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance#net-5-use-the-target-framework-moniker-option .

Comment: I'm not sure which part you are referring to to conclude that this weren't supported. The only Windows Runtime APIs not supported are those in the Windows 10 UI framework (that never got a name, so it's hard to talk about it). WinUI 2/3 seem to be fully supported, so any Windows Runtime components based on those types should work just fine. If you cannot get this to work, you should ask about the **specific** issue you run into, ideally with a [mcve].

Comment: I updated question with example and more

Comment: The link you reference explains that types in the *Windows.UI.Xaml* namespace aren't supported by .NET 5 and later. WinUI (both 2 and 3) live in the *Microsoft.UI.Xaml* namespace, so the document doesn't apply here. I don't know why (or where) the C# compiler is looking for `IXamlMetadataProviderMethods`. This isn't a type I'm familiar with. The XAML machinery needs [`IXamlMetadataProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.markup.ixamlmetadataprovider) only, so this may be a peculiarity of .NET's interpretation of the Windows Runtime.

Comment: Any ideas? Do you think contacting Microsoft would be on spot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue should be fixed by updating Windows App SDK to 1.1.0-preview2. More information in this [post](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT/issues/1148#issuecomment-1104582869).

Comment: Did that actually work for you? I'm getting this same issue even now with Windows App SDK 1.1.5.